# SlickGrid-rotated column headers

Tags: slickgrid, tableheader

How can I rotate my column headers 90 degrees? I've tried this, but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
.slick-column-name {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those has not yet found a good solution:

```
 /* Rotate the header*/
.slick-column-name {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;

    margin-top: 90px !important;
    font-size: 0.8em;

    display: block;


}
/* set the header height*/
.slick-header-columns, .slick-header-column {
    height: 100px !important;
    background-image: url('');
}
```

The above CSS rotates the header name, and moves it down 90px, it sizes the header to be of 100px in height. You can change the 90px and 100px to whatever you want.

Comment: This works well, except I set all the transform-origin: 0 0;

Answer (score 0):

It works if you replace the `<span>` tag with the header name with a `<div>` tag in slick.grid.js. Somehow transformation works only for div tags.

Comment: It's likely due to the CSS `display` rule. Setting those spans to `display: block` should get the rotation working.