# Vertically align vertical text in SlickGrid header

Tags: header, vertical-alignment, slickgrid, vertical-text

I am changing the height of a SlickGrid header and rotating the text in the header with the following CSS:

```
.slick-column-name {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.slick-header-columns, .slick-header-column {
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

For a better understanding, please take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Nvc3/1/

The rotated text in the header is centered and cut off. How can I change the alignment, so that it starts on the bottom (the text should be left-aligned before the -90° rotation)?

The width of one of the columns is different on purpose.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917916/slickgrid-rotated-column-headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nvc3/5/) I played around for a while. Basically the problem was that the origin of rotation was the middle of your text/header. Since "Else else SOmeshing Else" is significantly longer than the other column names, it sticks out on both sides. Either way - changing the origin of location to the beginning of the text solves this issue. Then to center um...`horizontally`(after the rotation) the text we put a margin-left of `40%` - at leat that looks good in Chrome, not exactly sure why it's not `50%`. To center the text um...`vertically`(after the rotation) we just add a text-indent of `-235px`, which is dictated by the height chosen here to fit the text, which is `250px`.